# Greek characters in gcc and warning

Tags: c, gcc, encoding

I have a simple problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c=getc(stdin);
    if (c=='φ')
    {
        printf("in");
    }
}
```

This piece of code does behave strangely.Try it yourself if you want to.If you input the Greek character φ in console,the if statement is false.If you change 'φ' to 'f' and repeat it works like a charm.Also been getting the warning  multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]|.Any advice?Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Very probably your terminal emulator is using [UTF8](http://www.utf-8.com/) encoding. In that encoding `φ` (U+03C6 GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI)  is two bytes : `"\317\206"` (octal string) or `"\xCF\x86"` (hex string)

You can find a lot of explanation about reading UTF8 in C e.g. [this blog entry](http://zaemis.blogspot.fr/2011/06/reading-unicode-utf-8-by-hand-in-c.html)

Comment: I am using x term with the default settings.Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions for writing a function that reads a character encoded using UTF-8? Read up on UTF-8. There is enough information in the first byte to determine the length of the sequence.

Comment: so i should change something code wise?What about the warning i have been getting?

Comment: Are you sure about the translation?  I got bytes `\xCF` `\x86`, or Unicode U+03C6 (GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI).  I agree that it is a multibyte character and hence the comparison is effectively guaranteed to fail because the single byte returned by `getchar()` won't match the multiple bytes in the character constant.

Comment: Thanks. I used Gnome Character Map and the first phi I got was a mathematical one, not the greek one. Corrected!